# Taylor series summation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find  $$
1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{2}{6} + \dots + \frac{1}{3n + 1} + \frac{1}{3n + 2} - \frac{2}{3n + 3} + \dotsb.$$

I feel to solve this infinite series, you would need to use Taylor Series and probably find the function whose Taylor Series is represented by that, and then obviously calculate. I'm unsure about where to start, what to do to find the function represented by that series. It doesn't really seem to match up with the Taylor Series I'm familiar with. Could I get some help?

Comment: The old trick: (a) Instead of your series, write Taylor series: $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{2}{6}x^6+\ldots$. (b) Notice that $f'(x)$ is a lot simpler to sum and you can do it outright. (c) Integrate.

Comment: Thanks! What I got when I differentiated the f(x) you provided was $1 + x - 2x^2 + x^3 + x^4 - 2x^5...$ I don't know if I'm missing something here but how can I sum this outright?

Comment: What you've got is $(1+x-2x^2)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\ldots)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct method without the use of Taylor series :**

For every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, one has
\begin{align*} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \dfrac{1}{3n+1} + \dfrac{1}{3n+2} - \dfrac{2}{3n+3} & =  \sum_{n=0}^{N} \dfrac{1}{3n+1} + \dfrac{1}{3n+2} + \dfrac{1}{3n+3}- \dfrac{3}{3n+3} \\& =  \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left(\dfrac{1}{3n+1} + \dfrac{1}{3n+2} + \dfrac{1}{3n+3}\right)- \sum_{n=0}^{N} \dfrac{1}{n+1} \\
& =  \sum_{n=1}^{3N+3} \dfrac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \dfrac{1}{n} \\
& =  \ln(3N+3)+\gamma - \ln(N+1)-\gamma + o(1) \\
& =  \ln(3)+ o(1) 
\end{align*}

which leads to $$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{3n+1} + \dfrac{1}{3n+2} - \dfrac{2}{3n+3} = \ln(3)}$$

Comment: Oh wow that is so smart thank you!